# Возвращение результатов из потока с помощью глобальных переменных

Tags: многопоточность, lambda, c#

Почему следующий код возвращает 0:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

 class Program 
 {

   static long Factorial(long n) 
   { 
     long res = 1; 
     do 
     { 
       res = res * n; 
     } while(--n > 0); 
     return res; 
   }

   static void Main() 
   {   
     long res1 = 0, res2 = 0;

     long n1 = 5000, n2 = 10000;

     Thread t1 = new Thread(() => 
       { 
         res1 = Factorial(n1); 
       });

     Thread t2 = new Thread(() => { res2=Factorial(n2); });

     // Запускаем потоки 
     t1.Start();  t2.Start();

     // Ожидаем завершения потоков 
     t1.Join();  t2.Join();

     Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} equals {1}", n1, res1); 
     Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} equals {1}", n2, res2); 
   }

 }
```

Вывод:

```
Factorial of 5000 equals 0
Factorial of 10000 equals 0
```

Comment: Потому что 5000 и 10000 слишком большие. 

Попробуйте с 5 и 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Факториал от 5000 - это оооооооочень большое число. Скорее всего, во вселенной даже нет столько атомов. long хоть и позволяет представлять достаточно большие числа, но все же тут вы явно перегнули палку. В один прекрасный момент возникает переполнение, вследствие чего переменная res становится то отрицательной, то положительной, В итоге, когда n становится равной 4938 возникает ситуация, когда произведение res*n становится равным нулю (опять же из-за некорретного результата вследстиве переполнения. В действительности же это произведение будет очень большим по модулю отрицательным числом).

Как известно, в C# из соображений производительности отключена проверка переполнения результатов математических операций (таких операций в программе бывает огромное количество, и выполнять такую проверку с выбросом искючения очень накладно, это при том, что само  переполнение возникает крайне редко). Включить такую проверку можно, пометив необходимый участок кода блоком **checked { }**. Например так:

```
static long Factorial(long n)
{
    long res = 1;                
    do
    {
        checked 
        {
            res = res*n;
        }
    } while (--n > 0);        
    return res;
}
```

В этом случае вы при переполнении будете получать исключение **OverflowException**.
А вообще при работе с подобными числами стоит использовать специальный структуру BigInteger из сборки в System.Numerics.dll. Операции с ее экземплярами выполняются медленнее, чем с обычными int или long, но зато они позволяют корректно представить необходимое число.

Вот ваш метод с использованием BigInteger:

```
static BigInteger Factorial(long n)
{
    BigInteger res = 1;
    do
    {
        res = res*n;
    } while (--n > 0);
    return res;

}
```

а вот результат при n == 5000. Выглядит внушительно:

[image]

Comment: Супер! 

(и сколь долго считал?)

Comment: Факториал от 5000 считал 41 миллисекунду. ОТ 10 000 от 65 до 68 мс. 
Однако при повторных запусках на 5000 уходило 17-20 мс, а вот на 10 000 время оставалось прежним. Не беорусь судить, с чем 'mnjk связано, но в любом случае цифры внушитенльые

Comment: А по моим ощущениям -- быстро.

Я тоже не знаю наверняка, почему такая разница между первым и остальными запусками. Могу предположить, что дело в отложенной JIT-компиляции C# байткода (и кэшировании откомпилированных функций).

Comment: меня тут удивила скорее не разница между первым и вторым запуском, а то, что в случае с 5000 эта разница была, а в случае с 10 000 ее не было. А что касается временных показателей, то, конечно, для таких больших чисел это немного, но если говорить о производительности обычных арифметических операций, то разница огромна

Comment: Так я же про это и написал в своем предположении.

Смотрите.

Начинаем считать 5000. Интерпретируем байткод. Через некоторое время замечаем, что постоянно исполняем одни и те же фрагменты байт-кода. Очевидно, что часть из них это библиотечные функции BigInteger. Компилирем их, запоминаем и далее вызываем уже native (результат компиляции). При следующих запусках (первый раз 10000 и все остальные) находим, что они уже откомпилированы.

Думаю, если перегрузить машину, то результат (первый -- долго, остальные быстрее) повторится.

Comment: @avp вы, вероятно, не поняли, о чем я. Речь **не о том**, что в первый раз долго, а потом быстро, а о том, что в первый раз долго, а потом быстро выполняется для 5000, а для 10 000 и в первый раз долго, и во второй тоже

Comment: @DreamChild, нет, я все понял именно так, как Вы и рассказываете.

41 для 5000 это долго, а 20 для 5000 быстро.

65 для 10000 это быстро (и это и в первый подсчет 10000 и в остальные).

Получаем, что *долго* это только первый раз (так оказалось, что 5000), а **все остальные** -- *быстро*.

--

Я именно так понял, и именно про эту ситуацию строю догадки.

Comment: @avp да, тогда, пожалуй, вы правы

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к правильному ответу [@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild): не стоит пользоваться устаревшими потоками, и тем более передачей результатов через глобальные переменные. Пользуйтесь уже ставшим стандартным `async`/`await`:

```
class Program
{
    static Task<BigInteger> ComputeFactorial(long n)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                BigInteger result = 1;
                for (long i = 2; i < n; i++)
                    result *= i;
                return result;
            });
    }

    static async Task Run()
    {
        var t1 = ComputeFactorial(5000);
        var t2 = ComputeFactorial(10000);

        Console.WriteLine(await t1);
        Console.WriteLine(await t2);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run().Wait();
    }
}
```